# Replace pattern using SED

Tags: unix, sed

Below is my sample script (named test1.sh) -

---

```
o=$1   -- parameter to be changed (sample value - "$$START_DT")
p=$2   -- new value of the parameter
q=$3   -- file to be changed

var="${o}=${p}"
echo "$var1"   --- will look like $$START_DT=2014-08-13

sed  's/*${o}*/ c\${var}/g' $q > newfile.txt

echo "Variable value changed"
```

---

So basically I need to change a file with the following value -

```
$$STRT_DT=2014-08-01
```

to something like

```
$$STRT_DT=2014-08-23
```

I need help specifically with the SED command... what changes should I make in the SED statement.

Comment: use `"` instead of single quotes in sed while using variables.

Comment: No change in the output with that. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf -v o '%q' "$1"
printf -v p '%q' "$2"
q=$3

sed "/^$o=/s|.*|$o=$p|" "$q"  # > newfile.txt
```